# How To Have A PHP if statment and execute fwrite if, if stament is correct

Tags: php, html, fwrite

I am trying to have a html form with checkboxs. I then have php to validate the form and get the value for the check box. If the checkbox corresponds to a certain text then there will be a fwrite statment.

Here is the code for the html checkboxs:

```
<input class="choose" type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="Python">&nbsp; Python</label>
<input class="choose" type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="Java"> &nbsp; Java And Html(opitnal)</label>
<input class="choose" type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="PHP"> &nbsp; PHP And Html(optinal)</label>
```

And here is the PHP form validation:

```
if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {
    foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected) {
        $lan = $selected;
    }
}
```

And Here is the if statment:

```
$fh = fopen("myfile.php", "w") or die("Error! :(");
if ($lan == "Python") { 
    $page1 = "Some Code For The Fwrite";
    fwrite($fh, $page1);
}
```

The fopen works but the fwrite does not actually write to the file, it should write the code in the if statment to file.

Also The form validation seems to work as if i echo the check box it returns the correct thing!

Comment: You're opening the file ___after___ trying to write to it..... no wonder the write fails

Comment: yes sorry it is before in my script. i have changed it now

Comment: Your fopen and fwrite works perfectly. Where do you `echo` ?

Comment: I hope you also `fclose()` the file when you complete writing on it. I cannot tell if not closing causes the data not being saved but closing it will definitely help.

Comment: Are you sure the code in the `if` block runs? Maybe the `if` condition evaluates to `FALSE` and `fwrite()` doesn't have any chance to run.

Comment: The fwrite evaluates to TRUE and yes i do use fclose. I dont get why it doesnt work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`check_list[]` is an array which means if the user checks them all the `$lan` will not equal to `python` or `java` but will be equal to the last element of the array in your case is `PHP`, **your fwrite won't work if more than one checkbox is checked**

```
if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {
foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected) {
    $lan = $selected; //$lan will equal to the last value of the array, if more than one checkbox is ticked
}
```

}

you can open your file inside your `if` statement, this code will only work if python is checked

```
if($lan == 'Python'){
$file = fopen("myfile.php","w") or die("Error! :(");
$page1 = "Some Code For The Fwrite again";
fwrite($file,$page1);
fclose($file);
}
```